# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException:The column name is specified more than once in the SET clause

Tags: hibernate

I am facing a below issue while persisting data to a table.

Error :

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The column name 'SubFundId' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'SubFundId' may appear twice in the view definition.

My piece of code for persisting data is :

```
 @Transactional
            public FundSalesCreditCalcMethodDTO addNewSubFundCalculationMethod(FundSalesCreditCalcMethodDTO dto) {
                try{
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<Object> id = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findSelectedSubFund").setParameter("subFundId",dto.getSubFundId()).getResultList();
                    System.out.println("*********in addNewSubFundCalculationMethod " +id.toString());
                    if (id.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println("*********in addNewSubFundCalculationMethod: List is empty");
                        FundSalesCreditCalcMethod fundSalesCreditCalcMethod = new FundSalesCreditCalcMethod();
    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setSubFundId(dto.getSubFundId());

                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setEffectiveFromDate(dto.getEffectiveFromDate());
                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setEffectiveToDate(dto.getEffectiveToDate());
    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setCreatedBy(dto.getCreatedBy());
                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setCreatedOn(dto.getCreatedOn());
                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setLastUpdatedBy(dto.getLastUpdatedBy());
                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setLastUpdatedOn(dto.getLastUpdatedOn());

                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setSalesCreditCalcMethodId(1);
                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setPaymentFrequencyId(1);
                    Date date = new Date();
                    fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setFirstPaymentDate(date);
this.entityManager.persist(fundSalesCreditCalcMethod);

            }
        }
        catch(NoResultException exception){

        }

        this.entityManager.flush();
        return dto;
    }
    }
```

MApping with SubFund Table is as below:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="SubFundId", referencedColumnName = "SubFundId")
    private SubFund subFund;


    private long salesCreditCalcMethodId;
    private long subFundId;
    private Date effectiveFromDate;
    private Date effectiveToDate;
    private long paymentFrequencyId;
    private Date firstPaymentDate;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;
    private String createdBy;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;


Can anyone please help what is the issue.I have been struggling with it from morning.
```

Comment: Do you really want to have both subFund and subFundId fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class, you have two fields that are mapped to the same column `SubFundId` as below:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="SubFundId", referencedColumnName = "SubFundId")
private SubFund subFund;
```

AND

```
private long subFundId;
```

So, hibernate is now confused as to which field needs to be used for `subFundId` column.

To solve this either you remove field `long subFundId` or if you need both then place  **insertable = false, updatable = false** on `private long subFundId` as below :

```
@Column(name="SubFundId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Comment: @Madhusuddan: I tried this adding @Column(name="SubFundId", insertable = false, updatable = false)   But i am getting below error:                                                                      Cannot insert the value NULL into column
'SubFundId', table 'SFSKelvin.dbo.SC_FundSalesCreditCalcMethod'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: @shree Because you are not setting the `subFund` object. You need to set it using `fundSalesCreditCalcMethod.setSubFund(..)` method. You can get it from `session.load(SubFund.class, dto.getSubFundId());`

Comment: @madhusuddan; could you please also tell me...the referencedColumnName is the variable defined in the class or the column defined in the table.                                                                         @JoinColumn(name="SubFundId", referencedColumnName = "SubFundId")   the reference Column is from SubFund table                                                                                                    @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="SubFundId")
 private long id;

Comment: @madhusadan:  I got my answer..It should be the name of the column. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a reference to a SubFund entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="SubFundId", referencedColumnName = "SubFundId")
private SubFund subFund;
```

plus you've also declared a field which maps the same reference

```
private long subFundId;
```

Choose which one you want to keep, if you need to handle the entities at the same time keep the first, if in all your application they are handled separately you can save yourself some troubles and keep the second.

Comment: It is not referencing to the same column..It's a different column from different Table.